# isolcpus doesn't work on Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process-management, parameter

I added `isolcpus=0` to the end of the following line to the file /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=0"
```

The idea, as I understand it, is to reserve core 0 from having anything run on that core unless explicitly done so through taskset. However, when I launch the System Monitor, I see all cores being used even though I have not run any programs through taskset on core 0.

Is `isolcpus=0` supported only on some linux, or is it that I misunderstand its usage?

Comment: may be you should also execute `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`? however I have the same problem in RHEL 7, even after executing `grub2-mkconfig` "isolated" cores are still "used"

Comment: in another try i've set `isolcpus = 3,4,5,6` then I run my application on cores `3-13`. By some reason it used only cores `3,4,5,6` but I expect it to use `3-13`

Answer (score 0):

3.5 years later, I meet the same problem in Ubuntu19.04, and here is my solution, hope to help.

```
update-grub
```

this command will update your grub and you /proc/cmdline will show the updated kernel boot info.